# Test HTTP redirect to HTTPS on the live production server

Tags: http, redirect, https

I have a production server with a live website configured to use SSL. It has also been configured to redirect any HTTP URLs to the HTTPS.

I would like to be able to view the website from the server and test the redirect taking place.  Instead I get an error message about permissions.

If I type the the HTTP url from a different machine I am able to view the website, i.e. the HTTP url has automatically been converted into an HTTPS url.

The question is how can I test the HTTP redirect from the production server?

Answer (score 0):

You either make the webserver also listen to localhost (127.0.0.1), or you make the test bind to the external IP of the host.